# Unable to login with Net_SSH2 in PHP

Tags: php, ssh

I am attempting to SSH from PHP but I can not login when include in other file
I created ssh.php and place it to "root/include" directory of my server:

```
    include 'Net/SSH2.php';

    //Initialize ssh object
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('my_linux_address','ssh_port');
    //Login to the Linux host with provided root username and password
    if (!$ssh->login('username', 'pass')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
    echo $ssh->exec("ls -al");
```

And execute it by calling from browser: http://myserver/include/ssh.php
it work fine

Then I created the second file: ssh2.php, place it to "root" directory
ssh2.php file simply:

```
include 'include/ssh.php';
```

Finally I run ssh2.php from brower: http://myserver/ssh2.php -> "Login Failed"

Comment: Does that client implementation offer functions to get the error message from the login attempt? Note that your code only checks in total if the login failed. It is unclear _why_ it failed in your case. Also take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where php logs additional information about errors to.